# How I display my current location in google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I wants to display my location in android device in google may using marker. I have written the following code. But there has no marker in the map. I also implement the LocationListener. But no marker. I am thankful to you if you send some code or give some suggestion. 
I am also checking the isProviderAvailable and provider. They are not coming properly. isProviderAvailable returns false. Is I have to change some facility on my device? or any other problem. Please share your thought. I am waiting.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
private String provider = null;
private Marker mCurrentPosition = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);


    Toast.makeText(this, "locateCurrentPosition Test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (isProviderAvailable() && (provider != null)) {
        locateCurrentPosition();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Not satisfied:"+isProviderAvailable(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private void locateCurrentPosition() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "locateCurrentPosition", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    int status = getPackageManager().checkPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            getPackageName());

    if (status == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        updateWithNewLocation(location);
        //  mLocationManager.addGpsStatusListener(this);
        long minTime = 5000;// ms
        float minDist = 5.0f;// meter
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTime, minDist,
                this);
    }
}


private boolean isProviderAvailable() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(
            Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);

    provider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if (mLocationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

        return true;
    }

    if (mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        provider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
        return true;
    }

    if (provider != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void updateWithNewLocation(Location location) {

    if (location != null && provider != null) {
        double lng = location.getLongitude();
        double lat = location.getLatitude();

        addBoundaryToCurrentPosition(lat, lng);

        CameraPosition camPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                .target(new LatLng(lat, lng)).zoom(10f).build();

        if (mMap != null)
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(camPosition));
    } else {
        Log.d("Location error", "Something went wrong");
    }
}


private void addBoundaryToCurrentPosition(double lat, double lang) {

    MarkerOptions mMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    mMarkerOptions.position(new LatLng(lat, lang));
    mMarkerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.marker));
    mMarkerOptions.anchor(0.5f, 0.5f);

    CircleOptions mOptions = new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(lat, lang)).radius(10000)
            .strokeColor(0x110000FF).strokeWidth(1).fillColor(0x110000FF);
    mMap.addCircle(mOptions);
    if (mCurrentPosition != null)
        mCurrentPosition.remove();
    mCurrentPosition = mMap.addMarker(mMarkerOptions);
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    updateWithNewLocation(location);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    updateWithNewLocation(null);
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    switch (status) {
        case LocationProvider.OUT_OF_SERVICE:
            break;
        case LocationProvider.TEMPORARILY_UNAVAILABLE:
            break;
        case LocationProvider.AVAILABLE:
            break;
    }
 }
}
```

Mainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.live.bbw.locationtest"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need to fetch current location lat and log value and also show marker.
fetch current location lat and long value and show marker on that used below code ...

```
public class MapLocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
SupportMapFragment mapFrag;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
Location mLastLocation;
Marker mCurrLocationMarker;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Map Location Activity");

    mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFrag.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    //stop location updates when Activity is no longer active
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    mGoogleMap=googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

    //Initialize Google Play Services
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location Permission already granted
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } else {
            //Request Location Permission
            checkLocationPermission();
        }
    }
    else {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    mLastLocation = location;
    if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
        mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
    }

    //Place current location marker
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

    //move map camera
    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,11));

}

public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
private void checkLocationPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Should we show an explanation?
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

            // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
            // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
            // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                    .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapLocationActivity.this,
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
                        }
                    })
                    .create()
                    .show();


        } else {
            // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION );
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                // location-related task you need to do.
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                        buildGoogleApiClient();
                    }
                    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {

                // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                // functionality that depends on this permission.
                Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return;
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

}

if you want only fetch current location lat and long value and some interval time used below class i make for separate ...

```
public class LocationFetcher implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {
// LogCat tag
private static final String TAG = LocationFetcher.class.getSimpleName();

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private Location mBestReading;

private static final long ONE_MIN = 1000 * 60;
private static final long TWO_MIN = ONE_MIN * 2;
private static final long FIVE_MIN = ONE_MIN * 5;
private static final long POLLING_FREQ = 1000 * 30;
private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_FREQ = 1000 * 5;
private static final float MIN_ACCURACY = 25.0f;
private static final float MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY = 500.0f;

private double mLattitude;
private double mLongitue;
private double mAltitude;
private Activity mContext;
private UpdatedLocation updatedLocation;
private Location mLocation;

public void setListener(UpdatedLocation updatedLocation) {
    if(mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        init();
    }
    this.updatedLocation = updatedLocation;
    updateLocation();
}

public void removeListener(){
    this.updatedLocation = null;
    mGoogleApiClient = null;
    /*if(mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }*/
}

public LocationFetcher(Activity context) {

    // First we need to check availability of play services
    this.mContext = context;
```

//        init();
        // Show location button click listener
    }

```
private void init(){
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(POLLING_FREQ);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_FREQ);

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mContext)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();


    PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, builder.build());
    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult result) {
            final Status status = result.getStatus();
            final LocationSettingsStates state = result.getLocationSettingsStates();
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the user
                    // a dialog.
                    try {
                        status.startResolutionForResult(mContext, 101);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                    // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                    // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}


private boolean servicesAvailable() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);

    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        return true;
    } else {
        //TODO ALERT
        Toast.makeText(mContext,
                "context device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        return false;
    }
}


/**
 * Google api callback methods
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
            + result.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

    if (servicesAvailable()) {

        // Get best last location measurement meeting criteria
        mBestReading = bestLastKnownLocation(MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY, FIVE_MIN);

        if (null == mBestReading
                || mBestReading.getAccuracy() > MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY
                || mBestReading.getTime() < System.currentTimeMillis() - TWO_MIN) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,  this);
                Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                if(location != null) {
                    mLocation = location;
                    mLattitude = location.getLatitude();
                    mLongitue = location.getLongitude();
```

//                        mLattitude = 23.0394070;
//                        mLongitue = 72.5638900;

```
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }
}
private Location bestLastKnownLocation(float minAccuracy, long minTime) {
    if(mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        Location bestResult = null;
        float bestAccuracy = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        long bestTime = Long.MIN_VALUE;

        // Get the best most recent location currently available
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(mContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Location mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

            if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
                float accuracy = mCurrentLocation.getAccuracy();
                long time = mCurrentLocation.getTime();

                if (accuracy < bestAccuracy) {
                    bestResult = mCurrentLocation;
                    bestAccuracy = accuracy;
                    bestTime = time;
                }
            }
            if (bestAccuracy > minAccuracy || bestTime < minTime) {
                return null;
            } else {
                mLocation = bestResult;
                mLattitude = bestResult.getLatitude();
                mLongitue = bestResult.getLongitude();
                mAltitude = bestResult.getAltitude();
```

//                    mLattitude = 23.0394070;
//                    mLongitue = 72.5638900;

```
                return bestResult;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(android.location.Location location) {
    mLocation = location;
    mLattitude = location.getLatitude();
    mLongitue = location.getLongitude();
```

//        mLattitude = 23.0394070;
//        mLongitue = 72.5638900;

```
    if(updatedLocation != null)
        updatedLocation.updateUI(location);
    CustomLogHandler.printDebuglog("Location","========>>" + location);

}

public Location getLocation(){
    return mLocation;
}
public double getLatitude(){
    return mLattitude;
}

public double getLongitude(){
    return mLongitue;
}


public double getAltitude(){
    return mAltitude;
}


public void updateLocation(){
    bestLastKnownLocation(MIN_LAST_READ_ACCURACY, FIVE_MIN);
}

public interface UpdatedLocation {
    public void updateUI(Location location);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

get latlng and put it in the code that i wrote bellow and put it on your OnMapReadyCallback

```
    // Add a marker in Sydney, Australia,
    // and move the map's camera to the same location.
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
            .title("Marker in Sydney"));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
```

if you have any other questions im there

Comment: Yes marker comes. But my criteria is to show marker in my current location.

Comment: put your lat and long in this code : "LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.852, 151.211);" i put random location . you have to get your location from location listener and put it into the following code

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve   `onLocationChanged` Listener and Add maker init

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
    if (location != null) {
        onLocationChanged(location);
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);

}
```

Implement your `onLocationChanged` like this

```
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    if (location != null) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        mMap.clear();
        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 13));
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Location not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```